# A million pages with 3 random internal links, what's the probability that each page has at least 1 link from another page?

Tags: probability

my question

- a website with a million **(1 000 000)** pages.
- each of these pages has a **random link section with 3 random links** to other pages of the same website (the 1 000 000 pages)
- **a webpage does not link itself or to the same page twice** from the random link section
- what is the **probability** that each webpage has **at least 1 link** from another webpage (from the random link section)?

I calculated this years ago and estimated 98%, but well I now want to double check as I'm going to publish a book and my probability math skills are more than rusty.

thx a lot.

Comment: can a site link to the same page twice?

Comment: hi, the three random links per page are unique per page. within one page there are no duplicate links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that **each** of the one million pages is linked to at least once is $0$ for all practical and impractical purposes.

We will instead compute the probability that a **given** page P is linked to at least once. The probability P is linked to by page Y is $\frac{3}{999999}$. So the probability it is not linked to by page Y is $1-\frac{3}{999999}$.

By independence, the probability that P is not linked to by *any page* is $\left(1-\frac{3}{999999}\right)^{999999}$.

This, to high accuracy, is $e^{-3}$. So the probability P is linked to by at least one page is very close to $1-e^{-3}$. This is quite close to $95\%$.